# Find angle in triangle (circle and bisection)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Given a triangle $ABC$, where $\alpha=46°$, $\gamma=60°$ and line that
>   bisects the angle in point $C$ intersects the circumcircle in point $D$, find angle $CBD$.

This is a short question, the correct answer being A) $104°$.

I can't figure out how to arrive at the correct answer despite it requires a simple observation I can't recognize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean $\angle A=46^\circ$ and $\angle C=60^\circ$?

Hint: $\angle CDB=\angle CAB$ and $\angle ACB=\angle DCB\div 2$.

Comment: That's right. I missed $\angle CDB$ being $\angle CAB$. Thanks.